# How to generate certificate of client_cert.der and client_key.der with create_selfsigned.py? I have to connect to UA expert with client

Tags: python, opc-ua

How to generate certificate of client_cert.der and client_key.der  with create_selfsigned.py? I have to connect to UA expert with client in our SASESP . How genertae thsoe certificates ? can any please share

tried to install certificate using th is command "python create_selfsigned.py --uri urn:open62541.client.espopcua --certificatename client" but coundnt able to generate cert and key

Comment: Ua Expert is an gerneric client which generates his certificats automatically. And SASESP seems also an data analyse tool ( client) - Can you explain your task more detailed?

Comment: we don't know the cerate_selfsigned.py codes, so nobody can help you. Also you don't provide any error output.

Comment: I think the script is part of the open62541 stack - But this is also not mention - Please improve your question.